# NJM4565S op-amp output to chassis ground

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

I have an old Fostex 4 track tape recorder. I am looking at the power supply circuit and do not understand the role or the output voltage of the NJM4565S op-amp.

The unit has a bad hum or buzz I am hunting down. The chassis ground is 5 V when testing it to the power supply negative.  Multi-meter positive is on the chassis ground and negative on the incoming power negative. Is this the correct behavior for that op-amp?

What is confusing me is that if you place the positive lead on any mixer knob housing or the RCA jack, you also see the 5V. I do not see anywhere on the boards where chassis ground and power ground connect.

One thing to note: the NJM4565S is 9 pin, so the pins are off by one on the datasheet. Pin 1 and 9 are the same (input voltage) as 8 on the datasheet.

I am very comfortable with electricity and schematics, I just only know the basics of electrical theory.

[image: Fostex X26 PB]

Answer (score 1):

The op-amps are connected as a rail splitter to take the floating 10V supply and effectively make it +/-5V.

Loud hum in old audio electronics is typically because of old dried-out electrolytic capacitors in the power supply, such as the 470uF/25V C0002 in your schematic. If you have an ESR meter check that it is within spec, or simply replace older large caps with new ones.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  The +/-5V is odd to me, so I am going to do some reading on that subject.  I already replaced that cap and another one of that size down stream.  It did not seem to make any impact.  I did replacing the OpAmp with another 4565 (connecting pad 1 to 9).  It changed the sound of the unit.  It was muffled and harsh.  I put the old one back and it improved the hum.  I have the unit back together, the hum I hear is in the Headphones.  It share circuitry with the monitor out jacks.  I do not have loud hum on that.  I am going to do more reading before reopening it.